# JQuery with MetroUI theme and scroll areas

Tags: jquery, cordova, scroll, microsoft-metro, area

I am playing around with JQuery and PhoneGap, using the MetroUI theme for my WP7.5 phone. I noticed the app and settings bar are scrolling with the content when flicking up and down, then redrawn once the scrolling comes to a stop. That makes it stand out like a cheap Metro UI imitation...
So how can I do something about this? Basically I want to divide the screen up into 3 areas, of which only one of them is scrolable.

I played around with the CSS files and got something working, 
check out  http://jsfiddle.net/mcsmarte/dNLA7/ 
but when taking it into use, the areas I don't want to move are placed correctly, but the entire screen still scrolls.
Any hints or advice?

Comment: Easier to diagnose if you could post down markup. Thanks...

Comment: Maybe you need to specify heigh, or maxheight on a div caontaining just the paragraphs in the exact location where you need it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like change the one div css to be like this:

```
.context{
    width:100%;
    height:350px;
    margin-top:40;
    margin-bottom:40;
    overflow: auto;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/dNLA7/6/

If I understood correctly...

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I almost gave up on this as I later read that the IE in the WP7.x phones didn't support the
position:fixed
It still scrolls the entire screen, bars as well at the very top and bottom of a list, but I can live with that.
Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure the bigger div have a overflow: hidden in it